# Using not to check if True

Tags: python, boolean

I've just done a very simplified version of the problem I'm trying to solve:

```
test = [False]
for element in test:
  if value not False:
    return True
```

This is to check an element is `True` in a list. However, this returns a `SyntaxError` on line 3.

Comment: `if test:` will work. `if not test:` when looking for `falsy` values.

Comment: I guess you mean something like `if element`

Comment: @Ronald you're right I screwed up screwing up.

Comment: Python is expecting a **binary operator** after `value`; `not` is a **unary operator**. Also, you have a `NameError`. `if element is not False` would work, although `if not element` is more Pythonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because

```
value not False
```

is not a valid Python syntax. You probably wanted

```
value is not False
```

The other issue is that you want `element` instead of `value`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax Error because `if value not False` makes no sense. You want to check `if value is not False`:

```
test = [False]
for element in test:
    if element is not False:
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has the built-in [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function which checks every element of a sequence for `True`-ness until it finds one:

```
>>> any([False, False, False, True, False]
True
```

The code at the [linked documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) looks very like yours:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score -4):

It looks like you want to iterate over a list of boolean values and return True as soon as you find a True one? If so you need to test the element, not the list:

```
test = [False]
for element in test:
    if element not False:
        return True
```

Comment: This fixes the `NameError`, but **not** the `SyntaxError`.